# How to get data from ajax response and assign to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below function always alerts `undefined`. Code execution is completed before the ajax request is completed. Kindly help .

```
function validateUser() {
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value
    var isuserValid = isvalidUser(user);
    alert("returned Result:" + isuserValid); // it always prints undefined,ajax request not completed.How can i wait for ajax request to complete 
    if (isuserValid) {
        alert("user Account found);
        } else {
            alert("Invalid user");
        }
    }

    function isValidUser(user) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'validateUser.jsp'
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
            data: {
                userName: user
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.trim() = "true")
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

//it always alerting undefined
```

Comment: Even the code block consider it has some problem, can you fix the typo first?

Comment: AJAX = **Asynchronous** Javascript and XML

Comment: use asynchronous ajax for them you have to add async:false in your ajax

Answer (score 0):

Put the alert in the success callback of the AJAX request. This will only run the alert after the AJAX request has completed.

Comment: I'll expect that this question will be closed soon. Its a duplicate. But you have an answer that points to the solution. Expand it so the OP learns more about asynchronous coding and you'll score points

Comment: I used ajax inside the method. Method call  returned before completing ajax call. So how can i wait for ajax call completion.

Comment: I hate giving people exact solutions to their problems though, they won't even think about the problem and will never learn. I like to point them in the right direction and let them find the solution themselves :)

Comment: you see that inside your AJAX call you are running an anonymous function with the argument (data). Try alert(data) inside that function and you should see some results :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want synchronous AJAX, you need to set `async: false` in your request; which is `true` by default.

```
function isValidUser(user) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'validateUser.jsp'
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'html'
            data: {
                userName: user
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.trim() = "true")
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

> Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.